# QGIS print composer WGS'84 grid, distance between gridlines

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to make an nautical chart in the QGIS print composer.
[image]

I have trouble getting the distance between my gridlines right. I need them to be a distance of whole minutes between. Now for some reason they are 1'2 apart. (I need them to be 003 46,00' - 003 47,00' - 003 48,00')

I tried with different CRS's and changing the interval in the grid settings, I can't get them right. What am I doing wrong?

Settings:

[image]

Comment: can you show us the grid settings you are using?

Comment: @IanTurton thnx for your quick repsonse. I've added a screengrab to the question

Comment: If you want your graticule to be an exact minute you have to set "Interval" to map unit. That will give you the option to define the X and Y interval in the units of the CRS of your choice. In this case since you want a minute you have to give ‭0.0166666666666666666666666666666 for the interval, since you have to define it in decimal degrees. This is 1/60=‭0.01666666666666666666666666666667‬

Comment: @GerardoJimenez You Sir are a hero! I apparently was thinking the wrong way around. I thought setting the interval to map unit was out of the question, but now see what my mistake was